# mysql optimize left join with subquery

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery, query-performance

I'm concerned about performance.

It is possibile to optimize the following mysql query?

```
SELECT u.name, t2.transactions, o2.orders FROM users AS u

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.aid AS tuid, SUM( IF( t.status = 1, t.amount, 0 ) ) AS transactions
    FROM transactions AS t 
    WHERE ( t.datetime BETWEEN ('2018-01-01 00:00:00') AND ( '2020-01-01 23:59:59' ) ) GROUP BY t.aid
) AS t2 ON tuid = u.id 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o.aid AS ouid, SUM(o.net) AS orders FROM orders AS o 
    WHERE ( o.date BETWEEN ('2018-01-01 00:00:00') AND ( '2020-01-01 23:59:59' ) ) GROUP BY o.aid 
) AS o2 ON ouid = u.id

WHERE u.status = 1
ORDER BY t2.transactions DESC
```

basically I need to sum users' data from multiple tables (and be able to order them)

Comment: Can you share some short and testable excerpt with dummy data for your query in http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no obvious query-performance antipattern in your query. Performance pretty much depends on the performance of the two subqueries with group by clauses.

Let's take a look at one of them to find some improvements.

```
SELECT t.aid AS tuid, 
       SUM( IF( t.status = 1, t.amount, 0 ) ) AS transactions
  FROM afs_transactions AS t 
 WHERE t.datetime BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-01 23:59:59'
 GROUP BY t.aid
```

This will be OK if you have an index on `afs_transactions.datetime`.

But the whole subquery can be rewritten

```
SELECT t.aid AS tuid, 
       SUM( t.amount ) AS transactions
  FROM afs_transactions AS t 
 WHERE t.datetime BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-01-01 23:59:59'
   AND t.status = 1
 GROUP BY t.aid
```

This query will take advantage of a compound index on `(status, datetime)`.  If you have many rows with `status` values not equal to `1`, and you have the compound index, the rewritten query will be faster.

**Pro tip**:  `BETWEEN` for datetime values is generally a poor choice, because, well, 59:59.  Try using `<` rather than BETWEEN's `<=` for the end of the range.

```
 WHERE t.datetime >= '2018-01-01'
   AND t.datetime <  '2020-01-02'   /* notice, it's the day after the range */
```

Comment: As you have mentioned `t.datetime <  '2020-01-02'` would that mean if there were records on `2020-01-02 00:00:00` then the result will be different or not equal?

Comment: `WHERE t.datetime < '2020-01-02'` chooses all records *before the first moment of 2-Jan-2020.* That is, it does not choose a record with the `datetime` value of `2020-01-02 00:00:00` . On the other hand `WHERE t.datetime BETWEEN something AND  '2020-01-02'` will choose that record; `WHERE col BETWEEN a AND b` means `WHERE col >= a AND col <= b`, using `>=` and `<=` rather than `>=` and `<`.

Comment: @o Thanks, so it's better to use comparison operator than between.

Comment: Another benefit:  That coding pattern works for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME(6)`, etc without any change.  _And_ it lets you avoid computing leap years, etc:  '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 2 YEAR`.  _And_ it avoids including all of Jan 1 2020, which you probably did not want!.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `JOIN ( SELECT ... )` used to be a performance killer (pre 5.6).  Now it *may* be a performance problem.

The alternative is

```
SELECT u.name,
       ( SELECT ... WHERE ...=u.id ) AS transactions,
       ( SELECT ... WHERE ...=u.id ) AS orders
    FROM users AS u
    WHERE  u.status = 1
    ORDER BY  transactions DESC
```

The first subquery is a correlated subquery and it looks like

```
       ( SELECT SUM( IF(status = 1, amount, 0)
            FROM  transactions
            WHERE  aid = u.id
              AND  datetime >= '2018-01-01'
              AND  datetime  < '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 2 YEAR`
       ) AS transactions
```

(The other one is similar.)

Indexes:

```
users:         INDEX(status, name, id)   -- "covering"
transactions:  INDEX(aid, datetime)
orders:        INDEX(aid, date)  or  INDEX(aid, date, net)
```